# Trying to return a string that contains double quotes

Tags: excel

Trying to return a text (or string) value that contains double quotes.

I have a basic validation in one of my cells:

=IF(C8=C9,"test "new" test")

where test "new" test is returned when C8 is equal to C9.

Receiving the error 'There's a problem with this formula.'

I believe the double quotes around the word new are causing the problem. If I delete them, the error is no longer coming. However, I need these double quotes as part of the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=IF(C8=C9,"test ""new"" test")
```

Double-quotes in strings need to be escaped by doubling them up.